# GPS won't receive forced Lat Long values in Android Emulator

Tags: android, gps, location, telnet

GPS provider won't receive any values either from Telnet or DDMS. Instead all forced values get sent to the Passive provider. Why is this? Everything I have read indicates it should be sent to the GPS provider.

Further, for some reason, GPS is picking up a value of 0, 0 as a default.

Can somebody explain why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this if anyone is curious.

You need to have code in there that makes a request to find an updated location, otherwise the telnet or DDMS values will not be passed to your emulator. They only get passed upon the code looking for updates.